# Is it possible to run the same source code in eclipse and android studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am new to android development, So I am not sure if this question is very silly

I was wondering if the same source code can run in both eclipse and android studio

If this is possible how to do it, and what points should be considered?

If not what are the road blocks to accomplish this.

Comment: You don't "run the code in an IDE"

Comment: @Selvin what I mean by "run" is the code should get executed using respective build tools without making any actual code changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: Yes, you can "write" (not run) in both IDE's.

Aside: You really don't even need an IDE. If using Gradle, you can write code using any text-editor, then compile, build, test, and install all using Gradle.

> If this is possible how to do it?

Well, Android Studio can import Eclipse projects. That is pretty well documented.

Eclipse (unofficially) has an Andmore project and also supports Gradle projects.

> what are the road blocks to accomplish this

If using Eclipse, it's not supported by the Android team anymore, and you'll likely be missing out on features that are actively added to Android Studio.